# Каждые 20 секунд добавляется строка в таблицу с новыми данными, полученными с сервера

Tags: javascript

Подскажите , есть где-нибудь пример такого кейса на чистом JavaScript: идет запрос на сервер (fetch например) и в real time идет добавление строки таблицы с данными из сервера, каждые 20 секунд дергается метод и мы получаем данные и сразу загружаем в таблицу (в таблицу добавляется новая строка с данными каждые 20 секунд).

Или может быть какой-нибудь плагин для этого. Нужно сделать быстро

Comment: А может быть сразу получать все данные и выводить их через 20 секунд порциями? Через setInterval?

Comment: @РоманТатаринов не думаю, все таки каждые 20 секунд информация (еще не полученная) может измениться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример. Для асинхронных запросов используется библиотека **fetch**, в качестве API - *openlibrary.org*, табличка рендерится "вручную" с помощью JS.

Это только пример, сегодня это всё делается с помощью *Angular/React/Vue* совсем иначе.

```js
const URL = 'https://openlibrary.org/api/books';
const numbers = ["8020409262", "0261103407", "9781565116696", "9780563536574", "0618042210", "0618517650", "9780061917806", "9780618640157", "0261102389", "0563528885", "9780048230911", "9780261102385", "9780048231147", "0048230464", "0048231126"];
const data = [];

function fetchData() {
  const number = generateRandom();
  const params = `?bibkeys=ISBN:${number}&jscmd=data&format=json`;
  return window.fetch(URL + params)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(body) {
      let parsed = '';
      try {
        parsed = JSON.parse(body);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error with parsing server response');
      }
      return parsed[`ISBN:${number}`] || {};
    });
}

function generateRandom() {
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
  return numbers[number];
}

function renderTable(rows) {
  function renderHeader(keys) {
    let header = '<tr>';
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      key = keys[i].split('_').join(' ');
      header += `<th>${key}</th>`;
    }
    header += '</tr>';
    return header;
  }

  function renderRow(item, keys) {
    let row = '<tr>';
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      key = keys[i];
      row += `<td>${item[key] || 'unknown'}</td>`;
    }
    row += '</tr>';
    return row;
  }

  let table = '<table><thead>';
  const keys = ['title', 'notes', 'number_of_pages', 'publish_date', 'url'];
  table += renderHeader(keys);
  table += '</thead><tbody>';
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    table += renderRow(rows[i], keys);
  }
  table += '</tbody></table>';
  return table;
}

setInterval(function() {
  fetchData().then(res => {
    data.push(res);
    document.body.innerHTML = renderTable(data);
  });
}, 10000);
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Hello world! (Wait for 10 seconds)
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/bypznhz6/33/)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял из вашего вопроса, вам нужен асинхронный запрос, чтобы в режиме реального времени что-то происходило без перезагрузки страницы. Объект [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) дает возможность из JavaScript делать HTTP-запросы к серверу без перезагрузки страницы, поэтому для отправки запросов я рекомендую использовать именно этот подход.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // создаем объект
xhr.open('GET', 'url', false); // конфигурируем GET запрос на url 
xhr.send(); // отправляем запрос

if (xhr.status == 200) {
  // результат обработайте и поместите в таблицу должным образом
  var result = xhr.responseText; // результат ответа на запрос
} else {
  // если статус не `200`, то произошла ошибка
}
```

Это то, что касается запроса, чтобы получить данные с сервера, нужно отправить запрос и получить ответ. Теперь перейдем ко второй части вашего вопроса - каждые 20 секунд дергать метод (интервал времени есть, код, предоставленный выше можем поместить в метод, изначально дописав его под свои нужды). Для этого нужна функция `setInterval`, которая запускает выполнение функции через указанный интервал времени регулярно, пока не будет остановлена через `clearInterval`. Все просто, вот пример:

```
function alertMessage() {
  // тут вместо вывода сообщения делайте запрос к серверу
  alert( "Я вызвалась!" );
}

// начать повторы с интервалом 20 секунд
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  alertMessage();
}, 20000);

// через 60 секунд (минута) остановить повторы
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
}, 60000);
```

Задержка задается в миллисекундах, 1000 миллисекунд равны 1 секунде. 
 Отсюда 20000 мс = 20 сек, а 60000 мс = 60 сек = 1 мин.

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

- [Использование XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)
- [Основы XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)
- [XMLHttpRequest POST, формы и кодировка](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms)
- [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)
- [setTimeout и setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)
- [Window setInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

P.S.: Хотел написать комментарий, да вот весь текст не поместился, поэтому опубликовал в качестве ответа. Так как кода в вопросе я не увидел - поэтому и в ответе связанного кода не много, советы, примеры и ссылки для изучения.